# How to Bind Attribute from Custom Polymer Element to angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

I created a custom element called my-slider-input which computes values from a user input. I need to take use these values in an angular controller. I'm wondering what's the best practice to do this?

Given this polymer element:

```
<dom-module id="my-slider-input">
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  <template>    
    <button id="input1">Input 1</button>
    <button id="input2">Input 1</button>
    <button id="input3">Input 1</button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-slider-input',
      properties: {

        value: {
          type: Object,
          computed: 'computeOutputs()',
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          notify: true
        },
        output1: {
          type: Number,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          notify: true
        },
        output3: {
          type: Number,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          notify: true
        },
        output2: {
          type: Number,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          notify: true
        }
      },
      listeners: {
        'input1.down': 'computeOutputs',
        'input2.down': 'computeOutputs',
        'input3.down': 'computeOutputs'
      },
      attached: function() {
          //Fired when this component is attached.
          this.computeOutputs();
      },
      computeOutputs: function() {
        var aggregateValue = {};

        this.output1 = this.complexFunction(1);
        this.output2 = this.complexFunction(2);
        this.output3 = this.complexFunction(3);

        aggregateValue.output1 = this.output1;
        aggregateValue.output2 = this.output2;
        aggregateValue.output3 = this.output3;

        return aggregateValue;
      },
      complexFunction: function(input) {

        //some complex calculations
        return 1;   
      }
    });
    })();
  </script>
```

I want to get the outputs of my-slider-input, I know I can create/listen for event notifications. How can I get the output for an angularjs controller?

How do I do something like this?

```
<div ng-Controller="myController">
    <my-slider-input value="{{outputAggregateValue}}"></my-slider-value>
</div>
```

or

Should I do something like this?

```
<div ng-Controller="myController">
    <my-slider-input output1="{{output1}}" output2="{{output2}}" output1="{{output3}}"></my-slider-value>
</div>
```

Currently in either scenario, the $scope values are not updated.

If this isn't the best way (2-way vs 1-way), how do I get the output out of my custom element and work with it in my controller?

Here's a jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/kosetiyelu/edit?html,output

Thanks in advance!
-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is best to use the `angular-bind-polymer` directive from [here](https://github.com/eee-c/angular-bind-polymer). The code is already written and it is working, so no need for you to implement it by yourself.

Instructions from the aforementioned page:

> This will only work if the Polymer element publishes and reflects
>   attributes. That is, it is insufficient to declare attributes:
>
> To mark the out attribute as reflectable, declare it as such with the
>   publish property:

Your element should therefore look like this:

```
<polymer-element name="x-double" attributes="in out">
  <template><!-- ... --></template>
  <script>
    Polymer("x-double", {
      publish: {
        out: {value: 0, reflect: true}
      },
      // ...
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

After that, just add the `bind-polymer` to your custom elements within the HTML code.

**EDIT**: Since the author is using Polymer 1.0, I have found another tutorial for passing data from Polymer to Angular: http://jcrowther.io/2015/05/26/using-polymer-webcomponents-with-angular-js/. In this tutorial, `angular-bind-polymer` is also used so I don't think the *plugin* is Polymer 0.5 specific.

**EDIT 2**: I have now noticed that the above tutorial does not use Polymer **1.0**, but Polymer **0.9**.

Comment: I believe the answer you gave is for Polymer 0.5, but there is evidence the OP is using Polymer 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I am using Polymer 1.0 thanks for pointing that out @ScottMiles

Comment: @alesc I added bind-polymer directive to my custom element but it's still not binding. I made sure that the reflectToAttribute and notify is set to true. Am I missing something? I followed the instructions,  could you please take a look and see? Is it because I'm using Polymer 1.0? http://jsbin.com/jasipaxoxo/edit?html,output

Comment: @ScottMiles I think the `angular-bind-polymer` also works for Polymer 1.0. I have found a new tutorial with Polymer 1.0 and it also uses it (and it works).

Comment: @Danprime I have updated my post with another tutorial, which uses Polymer 0.9. I don't see any big differences between your code, except that the author doesn't use the `notify` property and does use the `type` property.

Comment: @alesc: extra info: the `notify` property only matters for solutions that listen to property-change events to observe changes. Solutions that use attributes will require `type` so Polymer can decode data encoded into attributes (which are always Strings). Fwiw, a solution based on `notify` would be superior (transcoding objects or arrays through attributes is expensive), but I don't know if one exists yet.

Comment: UPDATE: The angular-bind-polymer directive does work, though it mainly works with strings and non-complex objects.

Answer (score 1):

I can only help you with the Polymer side of your question, but here goes.

The code in your question looks like proper Polymer 1.0 code, but the code in the JS Bin is mixed up between Polymer 0.5 and 1.0. @alesc's answer is only for 0.5, so there is version confusion.

Fwiw, here is a JsBin with proper Polymer 1.0 code: http://jsbin.com/vevawi/edit?html,output

If you examine the output you can see that Polymer is reflecting the values back to the attributes as requested. As for why Angular is not picking them up, I can't help you.

Fwiw, because of the `notify: true` settings, Polymer is also sending property-change events. Specifically, the `my-slider-input` is sending `object1-changed`, `object2-changed`, `object3-changed`, and `value-changed` (non-bubbling) events. Maybe you can use those to update the values in the Angular scope.

Comment: Thanks for updaing JSBin, I did mean to use Polymer 1 instead of 0.5 hence the discrepancy between jsbin and the question posted. I noticed that in the jsbin the custom element is still not showing the three input buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ng-polymer-elements to do what you describe, it supports many polymer components out of the box and provides an easy way to add your own mappings for custom/other unsupported components.

Check here: https://gabiaxel.github.io/ng-polymer-elements/

From their documentation:
"There are two cases where you can't get Web Components to work with your AngularJS models:

1. Having Web Components update your model, for example
   `<paper-input value="{{myModel}}"></paper-input>`
   will not change myModel when the user changes the input text.
2. Binding anything other than a string, for example
   `<google-map map="{{myMap}}"><google-map>`
   will not work because the expression {{myMap}} will be treated as a string.
   Enters ng-polymer-elements."

Comment: Thanks for your comment/answer! In the end it was just